# Can somebody clarify the Java Memory Model final field semantics related to complete initialization?

Tags: java, multithreading

From the [Java Memory Model specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#d5e34106):

> An object is considered to be completely initialized when its constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final fields.

The part that confuses me is this sentence:

> A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final fields.

The subject of the sentence is

> A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized

The rest of the statement applies only to this subject. This suggests to me that there are some threads that can see a reference to an object *before* that object has been completely initialized.

If such threads exist, then the guarantee relating to final fields in this specification only applies *in some cases*.

In an old [Brian Goetz article from 2001](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074979/java-concurrency/double-checked-locking--clever--but-broken.html), Goetz describes a scenario:

> Suppose thread B comes along after the memory has been allocated and the resource field is set, but before the constructor is called. It sees that resource is not null, skips the synchronized block, and returns a reference to a partially constructed Resource!

This suggests that there are in fact threads out there that can see references to objects before they are completely initialized.

Goetz then goes on to explain how using `volatile` doesn't help get around this problem, either.

So, how do I guarantee that some Object B cannot see some new ObjectA before ObjectA is completely initialized? It seems using final fields only helps if these conditions are already satisfied.

Comment: *So, how do I guarantee that some Object B cannot see some new ObjectA before ObjectA is completely initialized?* Don't leak `this` in the constructor and you should be fine.

Comment: I guess i'm looking for something in the JMM that explicitly states when we have these problems... I see how leaking `this` is a problem, but is it the one and only scenario where we have this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This suggests to me that there are some threads that can see a reference to an object before that object has been completely initialized.

That is correct.

It can happen if the constructor, or some method called by the constructor publishes `this` to some where that another thread can see it.  [Goetz et al](https://trove.nla.gov.au/work/20686287?q&versionId=46345724) calls this "unsafe publication" (IIRC.  My copy of the book is on a bookshelf ~2km away.)

> So, how do I guarantee that some Object B cannot see some new ObjectA before ObjectA is completely initialized?

The `ObjectA` constructors should not publish `this` to somewhere that some other thread could see it.   Then all is good<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - .... for some definitions of "all".  We still have to solve the world peace problem.</sup>

Comment: Interesting case... Are you certain that this is that the only case where this can happen? In the article I linked above, Goetz describes a different case (double-checked locking). It seems that the case that Goetz describes in that article is not the unsafe publication case, but some weird compiler instruction switcharoo case...

Comment: @tmsimont I think that article is outdated. DCL is workable in the current JMM, *if* the resource is properly immutable or declared volatile.

Comment: ya i was wondering about the date of the article, too, but he does go into a solid argument about how volatile doesn't work. i read this bit in the JMM about how immutability and final fields come to the rescue, but there's this caveat about only applying to "A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized" -- whatever that means

Comment: ah wait a minute... I think this part of the [JMM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#d5e34106) brings it home:

> Set the final fields for an object in that object's constructor; and do not write a reference to the object being constructed in a place where another thread can see it before the object's constructor is finished.

Comment: > f this is followed, then when the object is seen by another thread, that thread will always see the correctly constructed version of that object's final fields. It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are.

(this doesn't limit the scope of the thread being discussed)